# How to do Formatting and Rounding numbers in T-SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm worried about my result in converting the numbers to non-decimal and comma separated. I need to achieve proper formatting and rounding the numbers to currency as you can see in the examples below. Please help me.

```
select sum([TRANSACTION_PRICE]) from [dw_property_detail]
```

Wrong Result: `520400958.9`
Correct Result: `520,400,959`

```
select sum(nullif([ACTUAL_SIZE],0)) from [dw_property_detail]
```

Wrong Result: `25595.5`
Correct Result: `(25,596)`

```
select (Min(TRANSACTION_PRICE/ACTUAL_SIZE)) from [dw_property_detail]
```

Wrong Result: `3241412.6`
Correct Result: `($3,241,413)`

Comment: In general, if you have an application on top of the SQL server, you should do the formatting there.

Answer (score 0):

Given that it is 2017, I'd say there are two correct answers.

1. Use the `FORMAT` function introduced in 2012 as needed, with the appropriate code to output your desired results.
2. Formatting should be done client side when possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure many would agree that formatting belongs in the presentation layer.

That said, the following should help.  I should also add that Format() has some great functionality, it is NOT known to be a performer.

```
Declare @YourTable table (SomeVal decimal(18,2))
Insert Into @YourTable values
(-3241412.6),
(520400958.9)

Select Format(abs(round(SomeVal,0)),IIF(SomeVal<0,'($#,###)','$#,###'))
 From  @YourTable
```

Returns

```
($3,241,413)
$520,400,959
```

Answer (score -1):

As mentioned formatting should be left to the client but you can convert your amount to decimal, which will round it up, then convert it to money and use formatting of 1 to add the commas. You can get rid of .00 with substring if you want

```
select convert(varchar(50), convert(money, convert(decimal, YourValue)), 1)
```

[money format](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms187928.aspx#Anchor_6)

1   Commas every three digits to the left of the decimal point, and two digits to the right of the decimal point; for example, 3,510.92.

Or:

```
select '$ ' + reverse(stuff(reverse(convert(varchar(50), convert(money, convert(decimal, YourValue)), 1)), 1, 3, ''))
```